# jQuery not executing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first time working with jQuery, and I'm having trouble getting anything to execute. I've even tried throwing in an alert(), but it does not display. Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

This is the contents of my head element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
      $("#content").attr("width", $(window).width());
    }
    var container_width = $("#container").width();
    $("#footer").attr("width", container_width);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: you have not closed your `$(document).ready(function(){});` properly close with `})`

Comment: Why don't you post error message as shown in console?

Comment: Now's a good time to learn how the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) works.

Comment: jQuery 1.6? Why so old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing a bracket closing at last `};` to be `});`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
      $("#content").attr("width", $(window).width());
    }
    var container_width = $("#container").width();
    $("#footer").attr("width", container_width);
  });
```

**Note:**

Always check firebug or browser console to check for javascripts errors, it helps alot in these type of syntax errors.

You can also use Google Chrome for debugging your javascript and jquery code.

You can install [**firebug**](https://getfirebug.com/) by getting from [**here**](https://getfirebug.com/)

Comment: +1 even i'd advice to use chrome for debugging purpose, i find it better but maybe too much opinion-based

Comment: @A.Wolff let me add that as well.

Comment: @A.Wolff i use firefox and i mostly use Firebug that's why i suggested that

Comment: Ya, everyone has his own preferred choice when it comes to browser, car, pie and many more... ;)

Comment: Thanks very much, the actual problem was entirely unrelated (I had linked to the wrong version of jQuery) but it was your console suggestion that got me there in the end, so thank you very much :)